# Multiline NSString with a character limit per line

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring

I want to construct a multi line NSString (for printing purpose) with a character limit per line. Each line should have maximum of 25 characters. Number of lines can be anything based on the length of the string.
This is my approach which is not the best I guess. Whats is the best way to do this without manually checking the length of the string?

```
NSString *strComment;
NSMutableString* strCustomerComments = [NSMutableString string];

if([strComment length]<=25){
   [strCustomerComments appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strComment]];
}
else{
      [strCustomerComments appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",[[strComment substringToIndex:25],[strComment substringFromIndex:25]]];
   }
```

Comment: the string formatting step is completely superfluous (you could just use `description` so as to make your code more readable). Also use subscripting notation instead of `objectAtIndex:` and `objectForKey:`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Sorry for the clumsy code, I edited the code to be more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know it is helpful or not. here are the way that you can restrict number of character per line by following code.

```
NSString* strTemp = @"Welcome to the jannat and here you will get idea about what happend what you need my support so let start to figure out issue.Welcome to the jannat and here you will get idea about what happend what you need my support so let start to figure out issue.Welcome to the jannat and here you will get idea about what happend what you need my support so let start to figure out issue.Welcome to the jannat and here you will get idea about what happend what you need my support so let start to figure out issue.Welcome to the jannat and here you will get idea about what happend what you need my support so let start to figure out issue.Welcome to the jannat and here you will get idea about what happend what you need my support so let start to figure out issue.Welcome to the jannat and here you will get idea about what happend what you need my support so let start to figure out issue.+++++";

    NSMutableString* strNewString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    NSInteger addExtra = 0;

    NSInteger noofFixedCharecterPerLine = 25;


    for (int i=0; i<([strTemp length]/noofFixedCharecterPerLine); i++) {

        NSInteger FixedLength = noofFixedCharecterPerLine;
        if (i==(([strTemp length]/noofFixedCharecterPerLine))-1) {

            FixedLength = [strTemp length]-1 - ((i*noofFixedCharecterPerLine)+addExtra);


        }

        NSRange range = NSMakeRange((i*noofFixedCharecterPerLine)+addExtra, FixedLength);

        NSString* subString = [strTemp substringWithRange:range];

        if (i!=0) {
            [strNewString appendFormat:@"\n%@",subString];
            addExtra++;
        }
        else{
            [strNewString appendFormat:@"%@",subString];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"print : %@",strNewString);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @trojanfoe, i think this is batter option. there my be another way to restrict NSSting with specific number of charecter. but even if you can you used NSArray to story NSString. that is also data storage mechanism.

Comment: @None Thanks for the answer. This solved my problem. Just as a point, Can't we do something using NSAttributes?

Comment: @sajaz, thanks for your appreciation. I will look over it and let you know. If you get satisfaction then upvote it.

Comment: I don't understand how it is the accepted answer, when it is using hard-coded value and even the logic used is  skipping the last line.

Comment: @Vizllx, have you tried this logic? the person who asked the question will batter know that what he want. now he is getting what he want so why he is not accepted answer. weather accepted or rejected is matter of questioner not third party person. and he has tested batter because he know what he want.

Comment: RIP English.....@None   I have not indicated you by anyway.  I have just said what I felt about the logic of the program which is not valid.

Comment: @sorry dude. but i have tested it and working fine at my end.

Comment: Guys, I tested the code. It doesn't leave off the last line, but the last character of each line. But thats enough for me to fine tune the code and use it. Thats why I have marked it as accepted answer

Comment: Original code leaves out the last character of each line. We need to change the the NSRange to this NSRange range = NSMakeRange((i*noofFixedCharecterPerLine)+addExtra, FixedLength+1);

Answer (score 0):

*I have very quick method `-(NSArray *)breakStringIntoParts:(NSString *)sentence noOfParts:(int )noOfParts` which will surely help.*

**Here is the output of the code:-**

---

```
2015-05-11 13:04:25.120 vghnfgh[1011:15475] Line 1 Cntains 25 Characters i.e=I want to construct a mul
2015-05-11 13:04:25.121 vghnfgh[1011:15475] Line 2 Cntains 25 Characters i.e=ti line NSString (for pri
2015-05-11 13:04:25.122 vghnfgh[1011:15475] Line 3 Cntains 25 Characters i.e=nting purpose) with a cha
2015-05-11 13:04:25.122 vghnfgh[1011:15475] Line 4 Cntains 25 Characters i.e=racter limit per line. Ea
2015-05-11 13:04:25.122 vghnfgh[1011:15475] Line 5 Cntains 25 Characters i.e=ch line should have maxim
2015-05-11 13:04:25.122 vghnfgh[1011:15475] Line 6 Cntains 25 Characters i.e=um of 25 characters. Numb
2015-05-11 13:04:25.123 vghnfgh[1011:15475] Line 7 Cntains 25 Characters i.e=er of lines can be anythi
2015-05-11 13:04:25.123 vghnfgh[1011:15475] Line 8 Cntains 25 Characters i.e=ng based on the length of
2015-05-11 13:04:25.123 vghnfgh[1011:15475] Line 9 Cntains 25 Characters i.e= the string. This is my a
2015-05-11 13:04:25.123 vghnfgh[1011:15475] Line 10 Cntains 25 Characters i.e=pproach which is not the 
2015-05-11 13:04:25.123 vghnfgh[1011:15475] Line 11 Cntains 25 Characters i.e=best I guess. Whats is th
2015-05-11 13:04:25.139 vghnfgh[1011:15475] Line 12 Cntains 25 Characters i.e=e best way to do this wit
2015-05-11 13:04:25.139 vghnfgh[1011:15475] Line 13 Cntains 25 Characters i.e=hout manually checking th
2015-05-11 13:04:25.140 vghnfgh[1011:15475] Line 14 Cntains 25 Characters i.e=e length of the string?
```

---

**Here the code goes:-**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    line=@"I want to construct a multi line NSString (for printing purpose) with a character limit per line. Each line should have maximum of 25 characters. Number of lines can be anything based on the length of the string. This is my approach which is not the best I guess. Whats is the best way to do this without manually checking the length of the string?";

    NSMutableArray *arrSentenceParts=[self breakStringIntoParts:line noOfParts:25];

}

-(NSArray *)breakStringIntoParts:(NSString *)sentence noOfParts:(int )noOfParts
{
    NSMutableArray *arrResult=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //to store character array each of 25 character long.

    NSMutableArray *range=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    float rangeBreak =([sentence length] /noOfParts)+1; // this line divide how many objects will be there of 25 chars .

    for( int i=0;i<rangeBreak;i++)
    {
        [range addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]]; // storing each range in an array;

    }

    NSInteger characterCount=0; // responsible for iterating the whole sentence
    for (int j=0; j < [range count]; j++) {  //looping and adding 25 characters in each range of arrResult
        NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSInteger i=0; i < noOfParts; i++) {
            if(characterCount==[sentence length]) //stop the iteration on reaching last index of sentence
            {
                break;
            }
            NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [sentence characterAtIndex:characterCount]];
            [characters addObject:ichar]; //storing each  character in character array
            characterCount++;
        }
        [arrResult addObject:characters]; //now add final character array in arrResult
    }

    NSMutableArray *strMergedArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //will be storing   Array of strings
    for(int k=0;k<[arrResult count];k++)
    {
        NSString *resultString = [[arrResult objectAtIndex:k] componentsJoinedByString:@""]; //merging all the characters in specific index of arrResult and storing in NSString

        [strMergedArr addObject:resultString]; // adding one by one in Merged Array of Strings
         NSLog(@"Line %d Cntains 25 Characters i.e=%@",k+1,[strMergedArr objectAtIndex:k]); // demo purpose can be commented

    }

    return strMergedArr; // finally returning the Array of Strings , and each string length 25 Charcters .


}
```

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks for your comment, I have added comments later on better understanding.But to understand the code and it's functionality one must have to be analytical and need bit of intelligence, which seems some users don't have.

Comment: @trojanfoe [sentence characterAtIndex:characterCount] is used to store in NSString  because we cannot directly add unichar data type as an object in NSMutableArray.

Comment: Why are you dealing with characters in the first place, rather than sub-strings?

Comment: as that was needed for the logic used.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's one (untested):

```
- (NSString *)splitString:(NSString *)string byWidth:(NSUInteger)width
{
    NSUInteger index = 0, length = [string length];
    NSMutableString *outString = [NSMutableString new];
    while (length > 0) {
        if ([outString length] > 0)
            [outString appendString:@"\n"];
        NSUInteger lineLen = MIN(length - index, width);
        [outString appendString:[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, lineLen)]];
        length -= lineLen;
        index += lineLen;
    }
    return outString;
}
```